# Mockery mock method inside closure

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-4, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I have problem unit testing method inside closure called by `call_user_func()` example :

```
public function trans($lang, $callback)
{
   $this->sitepress->switch_lang($lang);
   call_user_func($callback);
}
```

on controller :

```
public function sendMail()
{
   $foo = $baz = 'something';
   $mail = $this->mailer;
   $this->helper->trans_c('en', function() use($foo, $baz, $mail) {
      $mail->send('Subject', $foo, $baz);
   });
}
```

test case :

```
public function testSomething()
{
   $helperMock = Mockery::mock('Acme\Helper');
   $helperMock->shouldReceive('trans_c')->once(); // passed

   $mailMock = Mockery::mock('Acme\Mail');
   $mailMock->shouldReceive('send')->once(); // got should be called 1 times instead 0

   $act = new SendMailController($helperMock, $mailMock);
   $act->sendMail();
}
```

how can I ensure that `->send()` method is called inside closure `trans_c()`

I tried with

```
$helperMock->shouldReceive('trans_c')->with('en', function() use($mailMock) {
   $mailMock->shouldReceive('send');
});
```

no luck. :(

well it works fine with passing `Mockery::type('Closure')` in the second param of `trans_c`, but I really need to ensure that method `send` from mailer class is called.

Comment: Please post the error you're getting. No luck does not help us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mocked class does not execute the real code by default. If you mock the helper it will check that the calls are being made but won't execute the anonymous function.

With mockery, you can configure the expectation so that the real method will be executed: `passthru();`

Try this:

```
$helperMock = Mockery::mock('Acme\Helper');
$helperMock
     ->shouldReceive('trans_c')
     ->once()
     ->passthru()
;
```

This is explained in [the docs](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html).

**EDIT**

Maybe you don't really need to mock the helper. If you mock the Mail class and expect the send method to be called once, just let the real helper do it.